# Nestjs websocket gateway, how to parse signed cookies from handshake for guard authorization?

Tags: node.js, cookies, socket.io, nestjs, nestjs-gateways

My guard contains the following code:

```
    let client: Socket = context.switchToWs().getClient();
    const sessionCookie = client.handshake.headers.cookie
      .split('; ')
      .find((cookie: string) => cookie.startsWith('session'))
      .split('=')[1];

    const sessionId = cookieParser.signedCookie(
      sessionCookie,
      process.env.CryptoKey,
    );

    console.log('SESSION ID',sessionId);
```

The resulting sessionId is still signed after calling cookieParse.signedCookie();

client.request.cookies and signedCookies are both undefined.

The session id is there and the cookie is being sent by the browser but I am unable to parse it in the gateway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue and found the answer. Your code is close, but the reason `cookieParser.signedCookie(...)` returns the signed cookie again is because some characters in the cookie value are encoded. So it doesn't detect the string as a signed cookie.

To fix this, you have to pass `decodeURIComponent(sessionCookie)` to the cookieParser instead.

```
    let client: Socket = context.switchToWs().getClient();
    const sessionCookie = client.handshake.headers.cookie
      .split('; ')
      .find((cookie: string) => cookie.startsWith('session'))
      .split('=')[1];

    const sessionId = cookieParser.signedCookie(
      decodeURIComponent(sessionCookie),
      process.env.CryptoKey,
    );

    console.log('SESSION ID',sessionId);
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to above this:

```js
client.handshake.headers.cookie?.split('; ')
```

Optional chaining (`.?`) is needed because there is possibility.